# Show that $\vec{X},\vec{Y}, \vec{Z}$ are orthogonal and find orthonormal basis vectors for the coordinate system with axes defined by them.

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I can show that they are orthogonal and also find the orthonormal basis by the Gram-Schmid method. But I don't understand how the coordinate systems axes are defined by them? Could anyone point me in the right direction? Also please feel free to tell me if I worked it out wrong.

$\vec{X} = (1,1,1),\vec{Y} = (-1,2-1), \vec{Z}=(-3,0,3)$

So $\vec{X}\cdot\vec{Y} = 0, \vec{Z}\cdot\vec{X} = 0, \vec{Z}\cdot\vec{Y} = 0$, So they are orthogonal.

Basis B;

$||\vec{X}|| = \sqrt1^2+1^2+1^2 = \sqrt3$

$||\vec{Y}|| = \sqrt-1^2+2^2+-1^2 = \sqrt2$

$||\vec{Z}|| = \sqrt-3^2+0^2+3^2 = 0$

$B = span(\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3}),(\frac{-1}{\sqrt2},\frac{2}{\sqrt2},\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}), (-3,0,3)$

Comment: $\|Z\| = \sqrt {(-3)^2 + 0^2 + 3^2} = 3\sqrt 2.$ And, for any vector $\|v\| = 0$ if and only if the vector is the zero vector.

Comment: Sorry how did you work this out? $-3^2$ is -9 and 3^2 = 9. -9+9 = 0, right?

When i enter this in my calculator it shows error, also tried google calculator.

Comment: A negative times a negative equals a positive. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k_jS1zVLWw $(-3)^2 = 9$

Comment: True. I won't trust the square button on my calculator ever again.

Comment: Never trust calculators.  Check your calculation on $\|Y\|$, too.